# Deleting copy constructor breaks inherited constructors

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, constructor, copy-constructor

I am trying to use the constructor inheritance feature of C++11. The following snippet (copied from somewhere, I don't remember whence) works completely fine:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base {
  Base() : Base(0) {}
  Base(int a) : Base(a, 0) {}
  Base(int a, double b) { std::cout << "Base(" << a << "," << b << ")" << std::endl; }
};

struct Derived : Base {
  using Base::Base;
  Derived(const Derived& that) = delete;  // This line is the culprit
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  Derived d1;
  Derived d2(42);
  Derived d3(42, 3.14);
}
```

That is, until the line marked by the comment is added; because then all hell breaks loose:

```bash
> g++ -std=c++11 -o test test.cpp
test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test.cpp:18:11: error: no matching function for call to ‘Derived::Derived()’
   Derived d1;
           ^
test.cpp:18:11: note: candidates are:
test.cpp:13:16: note: Derived::Derived(int)
    using Base::Base;
                ^
test.cpp:13:16: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
test.cpp:13:16: note: Derived::Derived(int, double)
test.cpp:13:16: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
```

It seems as if deleting the copy constructor also somehow made the default constructor from `Base` inaccessible. Googling the problem didn't bring up anything useful; SO suggested [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14912800/c11-non-static-member-initializers-and-deleted-copy-constructor), but as far as I understand, I do not use copy initialization in this snippet. Could someone shed some light on what has happened here?

(The compiler that generated the message above is GCC 4.8.2; however, clang returns a similar error message.)

Comment: The default constructor isn't inherited.

Comment: T.C. How so? In the `Derived d1;` line, I clearly see `Base()` called.

Comment: @T.C. choice of words is misleading. Of course, constructors are inherited - otherwise, you would not be able to call them from, the derived class.  It just used for different class.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that marking a copy constructor with `delete` makes it *user-declared*, which in effect deletes the default constructor of that class (in your case `Derived`). The behaviour can be seen in this simple code:

```
struct X
{
    X(const X&) = delete; // now the default constructor is not defined anymore
};

int main() 
{
    X x; // cannot construct X, default constructor is inaccessible 
}
```

As a side remark: even if `Base::Base()` would be inherited, the compiler would see it like 
`Derived(): Base(){}`. But `Derived` is deleted, so it cannot really call `Base::Base()`. In general, a `using Base::Base` statement is just syntactic sugar for the corresponding compiler-generated `Derived(params): Base(params){}`.

Comment: That was the link I was missing. Never thought deleting something would make count as "customizing" it. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidNemeskey Yes, it is indeed quite confusing, but that's how it works.

Comment: The standard term is *user-declared*.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you define a custom constructor you need to provide a default constructor explicitly. I.e.

```
Derived::Derived() = default;
```

Answer (score 4):

Inheriting constructors doesn't get the special constructors -- empty, copy, move.  This is because what you are asking for literally is almost always a bad idea.

---

Examine:

```
struct base {
  std::vector<int> data;
  base(base const&)=default;
  base(base&&)=default;
  base(size_t n):data(n) {}
  base()=default;
};

struct derived:base {
  using base::base;
  std::vector<char> more_data;
};
```

do you *really* want `derived(base const&)` to exist?  Or `derived(base&&)`?  Both would hopelessly slice `derived`.

The danger of those operations happening "accidentally" means you have to bring them in explicitly if you want them.

---

The copy/move/default ctors, by default, happen to just call the parent version, plus the ctors of member variables.  There is no need (usually) to involve inheriting them from your parent.

However, once you `=delete`, `=default` or define one of these special ctors, the other ones stop being generated by the compiler.  So you have to `=default` the other ones, if you still want them to stick around.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Even `=default` counts as user-declared?

Comment: @DavidNemeskey No.  First, because I was sloppy.  Second, because user-declared is a phrase defined in the standard (I believe), and I'm avoiding using those, because they have careful technical meanings.  But `=default` can have some effects -- if you `=default` the copy ctor, the move ctor is suppressed, and vice versa.  [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e1e31f3323dc0855).  The same isn't true of `=default` the nullary ctor.  [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c77e82287c0427e)